# Would I lose my vested RSU shares if I left the company?

Tags: stocks

I had some RSU shares vest back in February. About a week later the stock fell so I never sold them. I'm considering a new place of employment, and wondering if I would lose these vested shares if I were to leave the company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vested shares belong to you. Their value was recognized as your salary when they vested, and from that point on these are just shares that you own.

Comment: Note that this is different to vested OPTIONS. Vested options provide you an option to buy.